# How can I apply conditional formatting in C++ MFC?

Tags: c++, excel, mfc, conditional-formatting, excel-automation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb404903(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Microsoft provides example codes in C# and Visual Basic.

For example C# code as follows.

```
ApplicationClass excelApplication = null;
Workbook newWorkbook = null;
Worksheet targetSheet = null;
ColorScale cfColorScale = null;
IconSetCondition cfIconSet = null;
string paramWorkbookPath = @"C:\Temp\Test.xlsx";
object paramMissing = Type.Missing;
excelApplication = new ApplicationClass();
newWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
targetSheet = (Worksheet)(newWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
targetSheet.Name = "Conditional Formatting";

// Fill cells A1:A10 with sample data.
targetSheet.get_Range("A1", paramMissing).set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, 1);
targetSheet.get_Range("A2", paramMissing).set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, 2);
targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A2",
paramMissing).AutoFill(targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A10", paramMissing), XlAutoFillType.xlFillSeries);

// Create a two-color ColorScale object for the created sample data
// range.
cfColorScale = (ColorScale)(targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A10",
Type.Missing).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(2));

// Set the minimum threshold to red (0x000000FF) and maximum threshold
// to blue (0x00FF0000).
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[1].FormatColor.Color = 0x000000FF;
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[2].FormatColor.Color = 0x00FF0000;
```

How can we apply conditional formatting in C++ MFC?

```
range = ws.get_Range(COleVariant(_T("A1"), COleVariant(_T("A10")));
CFormatCondition fc;

fc = range.get_FormatConditions();
```